# A year has gone

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

What is the error in the following sentence

> A year has been gone by since he left us and we never hear any news of him.

According to my book **hear** should be replaced by **heard**.

But I think **hear** is correct and **a year has been gone** should be replaced by **a year has gone**

Am I right?

Comment: A year has been gone by since he left us and we have not heard any news of him........................He left us a year ago and we never hear any news of him.

Comment: @Bruce Murray Is it correct to say. A year has been gone

Comment: No, but a year has been and gone might be used as colloquial expression somewhere. However, it's not standard English.

Comment: It is not correct to say _a year has been gone by_ - it should be _has gone by_. _We never hear any news_ and _we have not heard any news_ are both acceptable. (The present tense is valid because they might have said something like "We hear news of him from time to time.")